# Wijmo styles to large

Tags: wijmo

I am using these references in a wijmo-prototype:

```
<link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/arctic/jquery-wijmo.css" class="wijmo-stylesheet-wijmo-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="arctic-jqueryui" />
<link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I find that some of the widgets and fonts are way to large for my layout.
Do I have to download these stylesheets and edit them manually or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to download and edit them manually. Another way is to keep these references and override only those classes which are necessary.
For eg. to change the font size and color of wijmenu items, you can override the following css class :

```
.wijmo-wijmenu-link {
   font-size: small !important;
   color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: No need to use !important!!!!
Just add the code áfter the original css, or increate the `specificity`